# resolving package resolutions in conda

Tags: python, anaconda, warnings, conda

Time and again, I'm faced with this disturbing problem of **`warning: possible package resolutions (only showing differing packages):`**

For instance:

```
junk ❯ conda update --all
Solving environment: - 
Warning: >10 possible package resolutions (only showing differing packages):
  - anaconda::cymem-1.31.2-py36_0, anaconda::plac-0.9.6-py36_0, anaconda::preshed-1.0.0-py36_0, conda-forge::joblib-0.11-py36_0
  - anaconda::cymem-1.31.2-py36_0, anaconda::plac-0.9.6-py36_0, anaconda::preshed-1.0.0-py36_0, defaults::joblib-0.11-py36_0
  - anaconda::cymem-1.31.2-py36_0, anaconda::preshed-1.0.0-py36_0, conda-forge::joblib-0.11-py36_0, defaults::plac-0.9.6-py36_0
  - anaconda::cymem-1.31.2-py36_0, anaconda::preshed-1.0.0-py36_0, defaults::joblib-0.11-py36_0, defaults::plac-0.9.6-py36_0
  - anaconda::preshed-1.0.0-py36_0, conda-forge::joblib-0.11-py36_0, defaults::cymem-1.31.2-py36_0, defaults::plac-0.9.6-py36_0
  - anaconda::preshed-1.0.0-py36_0, defaults::cymem-1.31.2-py36_0, defaults::joblib-0.11-py36_0, defaults::plac-0.9.6-py36_0
  - anaconda::plac-0.9.6-py36_0, anaconda::preshed-1.0.0-py36_0, conda-forge::joblib-0.11-py36_0, defaults::cymem-1.31.2-py36_0
  - anaconda::plac-0.9.6-py36_0, anaconda::preshed-1.0.0-py36_0, defaults::cymem-1.31.2-py36_0, defaults::joblib-0.11-py36_0
  - anaconda::plac-0.9.6-py36_0, conda-forge::joblib-0.11-py36_0, defaults::cymem-1.31.2-py36_0, defaults::preshed-1.0.0-py36_0
  - anaconda::cymem-1.31.2-py36_0, anaconda::plac-0.9.6-py36_0, conda-forge::joblib-0.11-py36_0, defaults::preshed-1.0.0-py36_0
  ... and othedone
```

How do I resolve these warnings? Is it possible to suppress it? Completely resolving it would definitely be nicer than suppressing it.

I have already tried doing:

```
$ conda update conda
```

But, unfortunately, that didn't solve the issue as claimed in: [`conda/issues/1580`](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/1580)

Comment: If you have the `anaconda` meta-package installed, it is not recommended to do `conda update --all`, since exactly this problem results. I would suggest updating packages individually if at all possible.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix package resolution warnings in conda?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56819911/how-to-fix-package-resolution-warnings-in-conda)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this following command this one resolved my issue

`conda update --strict-channel-priority --all`

Basically, this command force update all warning packages.