# How to fix package resolution warnings in conda?

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

Whenever I tried to `conda update --all` or `conda install package_name` I keep getting few package resolution warnings regarding `tensorflow-gpu`.

I couldn't figure out how to fix them? I would really appreciate any help.

[image: Warnings]

This is my `conda info` and `conda list`

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>conda info

     active environment : None
            shell level : 0
       user config file : C:\Users\Admin\.condarc
 populated config files : C:\Users\Admin\.condarc
          conda version : 4.7.5
    conda-build version : 3.18.6
         python version : 3.7.3.final.0
       virtual packages : __cuda=10.2
       base environment : C:\Users\Admin\Anaconda3  (writable)
           channel URLs : https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/win-64
                          https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch
          package cache : C:\Users\Admin\Anaconda3\pkgs
                          C:\Users\Admin\.conda\pkgs
                          C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\conda\conda\pkgs
       envs directories : C:\Users\Admin\Anaconda3\envs
                          C:\Users\Admin\.conda\envs
                          C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs
               platform : win-64
             user-agent : conda/4.7.5 requests/2.22.0 CPython/3.7.3 Windows/10 Windows/10.0.18362
          administrator : True
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False


C:\WINDOWS\system32>conda list
# packages in environment at C:\Users\Admin\Anaconda3:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
_ipyw_jlab_nb_ext_conf    0.1.0                    py37_0
_tflow_select             2.1.0                       gpu    anaconda
absl-py                   0.7.1                    py37_0    conda-forge
anaconda-client           1.7.2                      py_0    conda-forge
anaconda-navigator        1.9.7                    py37_0
asn1crypto                0.24.0                py37_1003    conda-forge
astor                     0.7.1                      py_0    conda-forge
attrs                     19.1.0                     py_0    conda-forge
babel                     2.7.0                      py_0    conda-forge
backcall                  0.1.0                      py_0    conda-forge
beautifulsoup4            4.7.1                 py37_1001    conda-forge
blas                      1.0                         mkl
bleach                    3.1.0                      py_0    conda-forge
blinker                   1.4                        py_1    conda-forge
boto                      2.49.0                     py_0    conda-forge
boto3                     1.9.180                    py_0    conda-forge
botocore                  1.12.180                   py_0    conda-forge
bz2file                   0.98                       py_0    conda-forge
bzip2                     1.0.6             hfa6e2cd_1002    conda-forge
ca-certificates           2019.6.16            hecc5488_0    conda-forge
catboost                  0.15.2                   py37_0    conda-forge
certifi                   2019.6.16                py37_0    conda-forge
cffi                      1.12.3           py37hb32ad35_0    conda-forge
chardet                   3.0.4                 py37_1003    conda-forge
click                     7.0                        py_0    conda-forge
clyent                    1.2.2                      py_1    conda-forge
colorama                  0.4.1                      py_0    conda-forge
conda                     4.7.5                    py37_0    conda-forge
conda-build               3.18.6                   py37_0    conda-forge
conda-env                 2.6.0                         1    conda-forge
conda-package-handling    1.3.10                   py37_0    conda-forge
conda-verify              3.1.1                 py37_1000    conda-forge
contractions              0.0.18                   pypi_0    pypi
cryptography              2.7              py37hb32ad35_0    conda-forge
cudatoolkit               10.0.130                      0    anaconda
cudnn                     7.6.0                cuda10.0_0    anaconda
cycler                    0.10.0                     py_1    conda-forge
decorator                 4.4.0                      py_0    conda-forge
deepreplay                0.1.2a2                  pypi_0    pypi
defusedxml                0.5.0                      py_1    conda-forge
docutils                  0.14                  py37_1001    conda-forge
entrypoints               0.3                   py37_1000    conda-forge
filelock                  3.0.10                     py_0    conda-forge
flashtext                 2.7                      pypi_0    pypi
freetype                  2.10.0               h5db478b_0    conda-forge
future                    0.17.1                py37_1000    conda-forge
gast                      0.2.2                      py_0    conda-forge
gensim                    3.7.1            py37h6538335_1    conda-forge
glob2                     0.7                        py_0    conda-forge
grpcio                    1.16.1           py37h351948d_1
h5py                      2.9.0           nompi_py37h3cb27cb_1102    conda-forge
hdf5                      1.10.4          nompi_hcc15c50_1106    conda-forge
hyperas                   0.4.1                    pypi_0    pypi
hyperopt                  0.1.2                      py_0    conda-forge
icc_rt                    2019.0.0             h0cc432a_1
icu                       58.2                 ha66f8fd_1
idna                      2.8                   py37_1000    conda-forge
intel-openmp              2019.4                      245
ipykernel                 5.1.1            py37h39e3cac_0    conda-forge
ipython                   7.6.0            py37h5ca1d4c_0    conda-forge
ipython_genutils          0.2.0                      py_1    conda-forge
ipywidgets                7.4.2                      py_0    conda-forge
jedi                      0.14.0                   py37_0    conda-forge
jinja2                    2.10.1                     py_0    conda-forge
jmespath                  0.9.4                      py_0    conda-forge
joblib                    0.13.2                     py_0    conda-forge
jpeg                      9c                hfa6e2cd_1001    conda-forge
json5                     0.8.4                      py_0    conda-forge
jsonschema                3.0.1                    py37_0    conda-forge
jupyter                   1.0.0                      py_2    conda-forge
jupyter_client            5.2.4                      py_3    conda-forge
jupyter_console           6.0.0                      py_0    conda-forge
jupyter_core              4.4.0                      py_0    conda-forge
jupyterlab                1.0.0                    py37_0    conda-forge
jupyterlab_server         1.0.0                      py_0    conda-forge
keras                     2.2.4                    py37_1    conda-forge
keras-applications        1.0.7                      py_1    conda-forge
keras-preprocessing       1.0.9                      py_1    conda-forge
kiwisolver                1.1.0            py37he980bc4_0    conda-forge
libarchive                3.3.3             h4890af2_1005    conda-forge
libblas                   3.8.0                     8_mkl    conda-forge
libcblas                  3.8.0                     8_mkl    conda-forge
libgpuarray               0.7.6             hfa6e2cd_1003    conda-forge
libiconv                  1.15              hfa6e2cd_1005    conda-forge
liblapack                 3.8.0                     8_mkl    conda-forge
liblapacke                3.8.0                     8_mkl    conda-forge
liblief                   0.9.0                ha925a31_2
libpng                    1.6.37               h7602738_0    conda-forge
libprotobuf               3.8.0                h1a1b453_0    conda-forge
libsodium                 1.0.16            h2fa13f4_1001    conda-forge
libtiff                   4.0.10            h6512ee2_1003    conda-forge
libwebp                   1.0.2                hfa6e2cd_2    conda-forge
libxml2                   2.9.9                h9ce36c8_0    conda-forge
lightgbm                  2.2.3            py37h6538335_0    conda-forge
lz4-c                     1.8.3             he025d50_1001    conda-forge
lzo                       2.10              hfa6e2cd_1000    conda-forge
m2w64-gcc-libgfortran     5.3.0                         6
m2w64-gcc-libs            5.3.0                         7
m2w64-gcc-libs-core       5.3.0                         7
m2w64-gmp                 6.1.0                         2
m2w64-libwinpthread-git   5.0.0.4634.697f757               2
mako                      1.0.10                     py_0    conda-forge
markdown                  2.6.11                     py_0    conda-forge
markupsafe                1.1.1            py37hfa6e2cd_0    conda-forge
matplotlib                3.1.0                    py37_1    conda-forge
matplotlib-base           3.1.0            py37h2852a4a_1    conda-forge
menuinst                  1.4.16                   py37_0    conda-forge
missingno                 0.4.1                      py_0    conda-forge
mistune                   0.8.4           py37hfa6e2cd_1000    conda-forge
mkl                       2019.4                      245
mlxtend                   0.16.0                     py_0    conda-forge
msys2-conda-epoch         20160418                      1
navigator-updater         0.2.1                    py37_0
nbconvert                 5.5.0                      py_0    conda-forge
nbformat                  4.4.0                      py_1    conda-forge
nbopen                    0.6                      pypi_0    pypi
networkx                  2.3                        py_0    conda-forge
nltk                      3.2.5                      py_0    conda-forge
notebook                  5.7.8                    py37_1    conda-forge
numpy                     1.16.4           py37hc71023c_0    conda-forge
oauthlib                  3.0.1                      py_0    conda-forge
olefile                   0.46                       py_0    conda-forge
opencv                    4.1.0            py37hb4945ee_5    conda-forge
openssl                   1.1.1b               hfa6e2cd_2    conda-forge
pandas                    0.24.2           py37he350917_0    conda-forge
pandoc                    2.7.3                         0    conda-forge
pandocfilters             1.4.2                      py_1    conda-forge
parso                     0.5.0                      py_0    conda-forge
patsy                     0.5.1                      py_0    conda-forge
pickleshare               0.7.5                 py37_1000    conda-forge
pillow                    6.0.0            py37h9a613e6_0    conda-forge
pip                       19.1.1                   py37_0    conda-forge
pkginfo                   1.5.0.1                    py_0    conda-forge
prometheus_client         0.7.1                      py_0    conda-forge
prompt_toolkit            2.0.9                      py_0    conda-forge
protobuf                  3.8.0            py37he025d50_1    conda-forge
psutil                    5.6.3            py37hfa6e2cd_0    conda-forge
py-lief                   0.9.0            py37ha925a31_2
pycosat                   0.6.3           py37hfa6e2cd_1001    conda-forge
pycparser                 2.19                     py37_1    conda-forge
pygments                  2.4.2                      py_0    conda-forge
pygpu                     0.7.6           py37h452e1ab_1000    conda-forge
pyjwt                     1.7.1                      py_0    conda-forge
pymongo                   3.8.0            py37h6538335_0    conda-forge
pyopenssl                 19.0.0                   py37_0    conda-forge
pyparsing                 2.4.0                      py_0    conda-forge
pyqt                      5.9.2            py37h6538335_0    conda-forge
pyreadline                2.1                   py37_1000    conda-forge
pyrsistent                0.15.2           py37hfa6e2cd_0    conda-forge
pysocks                   1.7.0                    py37_0    conda-forge
python                    3.7.3                hb12ca83_0    conda-forge
python-crfsuite           0.9.6           py37he980bc4_1000    conda-forge
python-dateutil           2.8.0                      py_0    conda-forge
python-libarchive-c       2.8                   py37_1004    conda-forge
pytz                      2019.1                     py_0    conda-forge
pywin32                   224             py37hfa6e2cd_1000    conda-forge
pywinpty                  0.5.5                 py37_1000    conda-forge
pyyaml                    5.1.1            py37hfa6e2cd_0    conda-forge
pyzmq                     18.0.2           py37he7828b0_0    conda-forge
qt                        5.9.7            vc14h73c81de_0  [vc14]  anaconda
qtconsole                 4.5.1                      py_0    conda-forge
qtpy                      1.8.0                      py_0    conda-forge
requests                  2.22.0                   py37_0    conda-forge
requests-oauthlib         1.2.0                      py_0    conda-forge
ruamel_yaml               0.15.71         py37hfa6e2cd_1000    conda-forge
s3transfer                0.2.1                    py37_0    conda-forge
scikit-learn              0.21.2           py37h7208079_1    conda-forge
scipy                     1.2.1            py37h29ff71c_0
seaborn                   0.9.0                      py_1    conda-forge
send2trash                1.5.0                      py_0    conda-forge
setuptools                41.0.1                   py37_0    conda-forge
sip                       4.19.8          py37h6538335_1000    conda-forge
six                       1.12.0                py37_1000    conda-forge
smart_open                1.8.4                      py_0    conda-forge
soupsieve                 1.9.2                    py37_0    conda-forge
sqlite                    3.28.0               hfa6e2cd_0    conda-forge
statsmodels               0.10.0           py37hfa6e2cd_0    conda-forge
tensorboard               1.13.1                   py37_0    conda-forge
tensorflow                1.13.1          gpu_py37h83e5d6a_0    anaconda
tensorflow-base           1.13.1          gpu_py37h871c8ca_0    anaconda
tensorflow-estimator      1.13.0           py37h39e3cac_0    conda-forge
tensorflow-gpu            1.13.1               h0d30ee6_0    anaconda
termcolor                 1.1.0                      py_2    conda-forge
terminado                 0.8.2                    py37_0    conda-forge
testpath                  0.4.2                   py_1001    conda-forge
textblob                  0.15.3                     py_0    conda-forge
theano                    1.0.4           py37h6538335_1000    conda-forge
tk                        8.6.9             hfa6e2cd_1002    conda-forge
tornado                   6.0.3            py37hfa6e2cd_0    conda-forge
tqdm                      4.32.2                     py_0    conda-forge
traitlets                 4.3.2                 py37_1000    conda-forge
twython                   3.7.0                      py_0    conda-forge
urllib3                   1.24.3                   py37_0    conda-forge
vc                        14.1                 h0510ff6_4
vs2015_runtime            14.15.26706          h3a45250_4
vs2015_win-64             14.0.25420          h55c1224_11
wcwidth                   0.1.7                      py_1    conda-forge
webencodings              0.5.1                      py_1    conda-forge
werkzeug                  0.15.4                     py_0    conda-forge
wheel                     0.33.4                   py37_0    conda-forge
widgetsnbextension        3.4.2                 py37_1000    conda-forge
win_inet_pton             1.1.0                    py37_0    conda-forge
wincertstore              0.2                   py37_1002    conda-forge
winpty                    0.4.3                         4    conda-forge
wordcloud                 1.5.0           py37hfa6e2cd_1000    conda-forge
xgboost                   0.90                     pypi_0    pypi
xz                        5.2.4             h2fa13f4_1001    conda-forge
yaml                      0.1.7             hfa6e2cd_1001    conda-forge
zeromq                    4.3.1             he025d50_1000    conda-forge
zlib                      1.2.11            h2fa13f4_1004    conda-forge
zstd                      1.4.0                hd8a0e53_0    conda-forge
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`conda` found several ways in which to upgrade your environment. The output in your screenshot is truncated, but it looks like it can pick the same versions of several packages (tensorflow-base, cudatoolkit,...) from different channels.

Try to enforce strict channel priority:

```
conda update --strict-channel-priority --all
```

If that doesn't help, install one or more of those packages explicitly from a particular channel, so that conda no longer has to decide whether to take it from `anaconda::` or from `defaults::`.