# What do these conda warnings on tensorflow mean? Any side effects if I leave them alone and how to fix them?

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, anaconda3

I recently upgraded to tensorflow v2.3 on anaconda 2020.7 distribution. I am using Windows 10.

Whenever I run `conda update --all`, I encounter the following warning message;

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: -
Warning: 4 possible package resolutions (only showing differing packages):
  - anaconda/noarch::astunparse-1.6.3-py_0, anaconda/noarch::tensorflow-estimator-2.3.0-pyheb71bc4_0
  - anaconda/noarch::tensorflow-estimator-2.3.0-pyheb71bc4_0, defaults/noarch::astunparse-1.6.3-py_0
  - anaconda/noarch::astunparse-1.6.3-py_0, defaults/noarch::tensorflow-estimator-2.3.0-pyheb71bc4_0
  - defaults/noarch::astunparse-1.6.3-py_0, defaults/noarch::tensorflow-estimator-2.3.0-pyheb71bc4done
```

What does the warning mean? Any side effect if I ignore them?

How do I fix these warnings?

Comment: I've never seen this before, but from [the section in the code](https://github.com/conda/conda/blame/cb8826c8b11bb453362f8ea4fd4e618b71bdca09/conda/resolve.py#L1445) it appears like it only shows if a user has INFO level verbosity enabled (either `verbosity: 1` in the `.condarc` or used `-v` flag at command line). Hence, it could be something common, just that most users never enable verbosity. Not sure.

Comment: It's just a warning. Won't stop your code from running.

Comment: @KappagantulaChandrasekhar Ignoring warnings is the first step to going to programming hell. Leads to all sorts of warnings.

Comment: Found this very similar question that might help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56819911/how-to-fix-package-resolution-warnings-in-conda

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known bug in [conda](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/7173). As for now, it seems okay to ignore this warnings.

If you are not tight to conda, you could also give the standard pip a chance (although [using both at the same time does not work smoothly](https://www.anaconda.com/blog/using-pip-in-a-conda-environment)).

Answer (score 1):

These just mean that `astunparse-1.6.3-py_0` and `tensorflow-estimator-2.3.0-pyheb71bc4_0` could be updated too, does not affect anything at all in execution.
Please go ahead, and do not worry about these.