# Warning: 2 possible package resolutions only showing differing packages anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda

Well a similar question has been asked already: [resolving package resolutions in conda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50996083/resolving-package-resolutions-in-conda)

```
Solving environment: /
Warning: 2 possible package resolutions (only showing differing packages):
  - defaults/noarch::path.py-12.0.2-py_0, defaults/osx-64::path-13.2.0-py37_0
  - defaults/noarch::path.py-12.4.0-0, defaults/osx-64::path-13.1.0-py37done
```

Already tried the following:

```
conda update --strict-channel-priority --all
conda update --all
conda update anaconda
conda update conda
```

Nothing seems to resolve this! Will really appreciate any help.

Conda info ==> http://dpaste.com/2951Y1J

conda version: 4.8.3

conda build version: 3.18.11

OS: Mac OS 10.14 Mojave

TIA

Answer (score 10):

Hi recently I had the same problem, I'm just a newbie, but I found a way to solve it.

For example:

Warning: 2 possible package resolutions (only showing differing packages):

- defaults/noarch::sphinx-3.5.3-pyhd3eb1b0_0, defaults/win-64::docutils-0.17-py38haa95532_1
- defaults/noarch::sphinx-3.5.4-pyhd3eb1b0_0, defaults/win-64::docutils-0.16-py38done

**The solution is: conda update sphinx, and then conda update docutils just in case, use conda update (name). depending on the name**

Answer (score 1):

Alright, found the solution

```
conda install anaconda-clean
anaconda-clean --yes
conda update --all
```

Should resolve the issue.

Comment: Do we do it in the current environment or base environment?

Comment: DO NOT TRY THIS! You will lose all your configurations!! I hate this answer! Now I have to recreate all my configurations from ZERO!

Comment: This did delete all my environments, but did not solve the problem. Do not try this.

Comment: I did this in the base env of my miniconda, things work fine for now.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar Issue with

```
Solving environment: \
Warning: 2 possible package resolutions (only showing differing packages):
  - anaconda/win-64::dask-2022.7.0-py39haa95532_0, anaconda/win-64::dask-core-2022.7.0-py39haa95532_0, anaconda/win-64::distributed-2022.7.0-py39haa95532_0, anaconda/win-64::jupyter_client-7.3.4-py39haa95532_0, anaconda/win-64::tornado-6.1-py39h2bbff1b_0
  - anaconda/win-64::dask-2022.5.0-py39haa95532_0, anaconda/win-64::dask-core-2022.5.0-py39haa95532_0, anaconda/win-64::distributed-2022.5.0-py39haa95532_0, anaconda/win-64::jupyter_client-7.4.8-py39haa95532_0, anaconda/win-64::tornado-6.2-py39h2bbff1bdone
```

**Easy fix was for me to choose one of the packages mentioned and update it manually e.g.**

```
conda install -c conda-forge dask
```

After that I was able to `conda update --all` without the warning.

---

I guess this happens if some packages give ambigous dependencies so this can only be solved manually anyway https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/7173#issuecomment-472892512

Answer (score -1):

Just encountered this. What worked for me was:

```
conda update conda 
conda update anaconda
conda update conda
conda update anaconda
```

Note that in my case this needed to be run in this specific order (with repeats).