# (Ana)Conda fails upgrade with unresolved conflicts

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

A few years back i started using (Ana)Conda as a environment that works on OSX and Windows. But basically every time i run into the same problem... Upgrading the environment.
I know that here on stackoverflow there are multiple topics about conda and updating. But so far i didn't seen one how to overcome the conflicts( at least not one that works out for me). So forgive me if i ask the same question again...

First what have i done( today):
`conda install -c anaconda navigator-updater`
Resulting in huge amount of conflicts i can't say which ones my terminal history isn't going back far enough.
Based on [SO - how-do-i-update-anaconda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45197777/how-do-i-update-anaconda):
`conda update -n base conda`

```
python=3.9 -> pip -> setuptools
conda[version='>=4.10.3'] -> setuptools[version='>=31.0.1']
conda -> ruamel_yaml -> setuptools
conda -> setuptools[version='>=31.0.1']
anaconda==2021.11=py39_0 -> setuptools==58.0.4=py39hecd8cb5_0
conda-verify -> jinja2 -> setuptools
anaconda-navigator -> setuptools
conda-build -> setuptools
conda-build -> conda[version='>=4.5'] -> setuptools[version='>=31.0.1']
anaconda==2021.11=py39_0 -> anaconda-client==1.9.0=py39hecd8cb5_0 -> setuptools[version='>=18.5|>=20.0|>=30.0.0|>=39.0.0|>=49.6.0']
```

This are less conflicts but still not a upgrade.
Than based on [SO - resolving package resolutions in conda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50996083/resolving-package-resolutions-in-conda) I did this command:
`conda update --strict-channel-priority -n base conda`

```
UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found
to be incompatible with the existing python installation in your environment:

Specifications:

  - conda-env -> python[version='2.7.*|3.4.*|3.5.*']

Your python: python=3.9
```

Of course `conda update --strict-channel-priority -n base conda python=3.9` don't exist.
Result i'm close to the point where i normally finish: `brew uninstall --cask anaconda` followed by `brew install --cask anaconda`

So my main question is:

1. How do i resolve these conflicts so i can upgrade
2. As side question: If i conclude that restarting my environment(s) is more easy... What do i have to, to don't end up here over a few weeks / months / ...